# Admob Межстраничное обьявление

Tags: java, android

Как сделать появление межстраничного объявления при клике по кнопке?
Ниже представлен код. Где допущены ошибки? Делал по инструкции Admob-а Поправьте пожалуйста.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9777249340958310/3008582982");
        requestNewInterstitial ();

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Были ошибки в форматировании вопроса. :) В следующий раз выделяйте код целиком и жмите Ctrl+K или кнопку `{}`

Comment: Ок, спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: по существу вопроса, к сожалению, ничего не подскажу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас 2 проблемы:

1. Судя по коду метод ваш `requestNewInterstitial()` просто вызывает сам себя, ничего вообще не делая.
2. Вы нигде (судя по коду) не запрашиваете, собственно, рекламу у сервера.

Итого, согласно [документации](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd) вам надо (например, внутрь метода `requestNewInterstitial()`) добавить код загружающий рекламу.

```
//Создаём запрос серверу рекламы
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
//тут желательно добавить девайс в список тестовых, дабы не нарваться на бан
//за показ рекламы самому себе
//Начинаем загрузку рекламы
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```